# How to solve simple expression?

Tags: matlab, math

Which approach do I have to follow in order to calculate the expression below:

```
3.591*(y)*(1-y)^0.77=0.125
```

I am look forward to hear from you.

Comment: Any particular programming language ?

Comment: Preferably in R, but I want to know the value for y.

Comment: Is it possible to calculate manually?

Comment: I have access to matlab. Please I got stuck to this problem

Comment: [Wolfam Alpha seems to handle this quite well](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3.591*%28y%29*%281-y%29%5E0.77%3D0.125&dataset=), giving y = 0.0358, y = 0.9870.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this numerically using MATLAB (or the free MATLAB clone Octave) as follows:

```
octave:1>fun = @(x) 3.591*(x)*(1-x)^0.77-0.125
fun =

@(x) 3.591 * (x) * (1 - x) ^ 0.77 - 0.125

octave:2> fzero(fun,[0 0.5])
ans =  0.035800
octave:3> fzero(fun,[0.5 1.0])
ans =  0.98701
```